Cox Model - How to overcome small risk set after some time?
I am currently designing an Anderson-Gill model. After plotting the mean cumulative function (see below), I noticed that the confidence intervals become very large later, indeed too large for my liking.

My setup is best compared to a pre- and post-treatment comparison. Thus, subject i has a treatment after a random duration d, and I am interested in comparing the recurrent events in each of the phases.
Many subjects have this treatment early in period 1 and thus transition to period 2, so the risk set for period 1 becomes very small over time, and the comparison loses meaning.
What are possible solutions to still analyze this kind of data?
My initial thoughts are:

Strata by period (allow the baseline for each period to vary over time) and allow the coefficients to be time-varying.
Right now, I am only using a sub-sample. Thus, I could also add more subjects with a longer phase 1, which would mean oversampling those cases so the confidence intervals become smaller again.

I hope I described the setup and issue well enough. Let me know if I should elaborate more.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
